# My Discord.js is running but won't respond to commands

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I wanted to make a suggestions bot for my discord server so I coded when people do "!suggest " the bot will write a comfortable way for people to vote for that suggestion and for some reason the bot won't respond, I checked similar problems that happened to other people but the solutions didn't work for me.

Here's the code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")


module.exports = {
  name: "suggest",
  usage: "suggest <message>",
  description: "Send your Suggestion",
  category: "main",
  run: (client, message, args) => {
    
    if(!args.length) {
      return message.channel.send("Please Give the Suggestion")
    }
    
    let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find((x) => (x.name === "suggestion" || x.name === "suggestions"))
    
    
    if(!channel) {
      return message.channel.send("there is no channel with name - suggestions")
    }
                                                    
    
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor("SUGGESTION: " + message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL())
    .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
    .setColor("#ff2050")
    .setDescription(args.join(" "))
    .setTimestamp()
    
    
    channel.send(embed).then(m => {
      m.react("✅")
      m.react("❌")
    })
    

    
    message.channel.send("Sended Your Suggestion to " + channel)
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixing main errors**
On line 11 you have entered `if (!args.length) {`.
That will give you an undefined error causing the rest of your code to not work.
Replace that line with the following code:

```js
if(args.length < 1) {
    return message.channel.send("Please provide the Suggestion")
}
```

**Fixing spelling errors**
When you send the final message at the end of your code

```js
message.channel.send("Sended Your Suggestion to " + channel)
```

"Sended" is not a word and should be replaced with "Sent".